# How to get text(file names) present between anchor tags in PHP?

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I've following strings with me in which the file name is present in between anchor tags:

```
  $test1 = test<div class="comment_attach_file">
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_04/file_3b701923a804ed6f28c61c4cdc0ebcb2.txt" >phase2 screen.txt</a><br>
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_04/file_3b701923a804ed6f28c61c4cdc0ebcb2.txt" >Download</a>
            </div>;

  $test2 =  This is a holiday list.<div class="comment_attach_file">
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_04/file_2c96b997f03eefab317811e368731bb6.pdf" >Holiday List-2013.pdf</a><br>
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link_dwl"  href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_04/file_2c96b997f03eefab317811e368731bb6.pdf" >Download</a>
            </div>;

  $test3 = <div class="comment_attach_file">
            <a class="comment_attach_file_link" href="http://52.1.47.143/feed/download/year_2015/month_04/file_8479c0b60867fdce35ae94a668dfbba9.docx" >sample2.docx</a><br>
            </div>;
```

From the first string I want text(i.e. file name) **"phase2 screen.txt"**

From the second string I want text(i.e. file name) **"Holiday List-2013.pdf"**

From the third string I want text(i.e. file name) **"sample2.docx"**

How should I do in PHP using `$dom = new DOMDocument;`?

Please someone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use HTML parser for it. There are many tutorials on the web. Try something, and we'll help you if you'll face difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOMxpath to target that link that contains the text you want, use its class to point to it:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    @$dom->loadHTML(${"test{$i}"});
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $file_name = $xpath->evaluate('string(//a[@class="comment_attach_file_link"])');
    echo $file_name , '<br/>';
}
```

Or if you don't want to use xpath, you can get the anchor elements and check for its class, if its that one, get the `->nodeValue`:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    @$dom->loadHTML(${"test{$i}"});
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor) {
        if($anchor->getAttribute('class') === 'comment_attach_file_link') {
            echo $anchor->nodeValue, '<br/>';
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/b8RhsX)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value after the hash mark or anchor as shown in a user's browser: This isn't possible with "standard" HTTP as this value is never sent to the server (hence it won't be available in `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` or similar predefined variables). You would need some sort of JavaScript magic on the client side, e.g. to include this value as a POST parameter.

In dom you can use some function like this to get the links and change it according to your need

```
    function findAnchors($html)
{
    $links = array();
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $navbars = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($navbars as $navbar) {
        $id = $navbar->getAttribute('id');
        if ($id === "anchors") {
            $anchors = $navbar->getElementsByTagName('a');
            foreach ($anchors as $a) {
                $links[] = $doc->saveHTML($a);
            }
        }
    }
    return $links;
}
```